# Tower within a Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Consider the following tower of fields:

$$ K \subset M \subset L $$

If $ L/K$ is a finite Galois extension, then is it true that $ M/K $ is a Galois extension ? Is it also finite ?

It is clear to me that $ M/K$ is separable, but I can't see why it has to be also normal.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not necessarily. However it's true that $L/M$ is also galois.

Comment: @JackYoon: Thank you for your reply. I have one more question. If $L$ is the Hilbert Class field of $K$ (i.e. the maximal unramified Abelian extension) then is it true ?

Comment: Condition for $M/K$ being galois is if the appropriate subgroup of $G(L/K)$ which corresponds to $M$ (sorry I can't really remember the detail) a is normal subgroup. In an abelian group every subgroup is a normal subgroup so in any abelian extension this would be true.

Comment: Do you have any reference in mind for this criterion ?

Comment: I remember this from the course I took and I briefly recalled it from link http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/MA3D5/Galois.pdf. I would have thought any introductory text in galois theory would contain it though. It normally is part of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: $M/K$ is Galois if and only if $\operatorname{Gal}(L/M)$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$. In particular, recall that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal. This implies that if $L/K$ is an abelian extension, then $M/K$ is automatically Galois.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply's ! Eventually it is critical to have Abelian extension in order $ M/K$ be Galois. That's what I was missing. @Jack: I would like to ask you if it possible to make your comments as an answer, so I can accept (since you were the first who answered), and the thread move from the unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, the statement you asked for is false as the answer above. (well it is true that subextension of a finite extension is finite.) However if the extension is abelian then the statement is true by fundamental theorem of galois theory as every subgroup is normal in an abelian group.

Answer (score 3):

$\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2\,,\,i)\,/\,\Bbb Q\;\;\;$ is Galois , yet $\;\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)\,/\,\Bbb Q\;\;$ is not normal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! Actually I was looking for a case where this extension would be Galois, although I didn't write it properly in the question.

Comment: If $L/K$ is abelian, then every intermediate subfield will be Galois over $K$.  This is because $M/K$ is Galois if and only if $Gal(L/M)$ is normal in $Gal(L/K)$.