# for F ⊂ K ⊂ E if E/F ve E/K Galois gextensions then K/F is also Galois extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $E,K,F$ being fields such that $F \subset  K \subset  E$. I'm trying to find $E,K,F$ s.t. $E/K$ and $E/F$ are Galois, but $K/F$ is not. Could someone help to provide such fields ?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260660/tower-within-a-galois-extension) and the counterexample given there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Take $$E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,i),\quad K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\quad \text{and}\quad F=\mathbb Q.$$